# Finding difficulty in creating directive in place of jquery function in AngularJS 1.X

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Hi I am a newbie to angular js. I am creating a web page and in square container, I want to add images in aspect ratio. So, I have written a function in jquery (I know it's bad practice) and it is working fine. But as the function is going to be used in many pages for the same purpose, I want to make it as directive (better angular practice). I want to add that directive on `<img>` tag having 'feature-img' class'. I'm getting actual width and height of images from API call and have stored those in custom attributes (actual-width and actual-height). But actually I'm not getting the idea to create directive as function is bigger and there are many dom manipulations. Any help or perfect idea will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
    function getAspectRatioImage() {
    $scope.currentWidth = $('.parent-container').width();
    $scope.$apply();

    $('.square-container').each(function () {  
        $(this).css("width", $scope.currentWidth);
        $(this).css("height", $scope.currentWidth);

    });

    $('.feature-img').each(function () {
        var maxWidth = $scope.currentWidth; 
        var maxHeight = $scope.currentWidth;    
        var width = $(this).attr("actual-width");    
        var height = $(this).attr("actual-height");  
        var ratio = width / height;
        var margin, marginHalf;

        if(width > maxWidth || height > maxHeight){
            if(width > maxWidth && height > maxHeight){
                if(ratio > 1){  
                    $(this).css("width", maxWidth);  
                    $(this).css("height", maxWidth/ratio);        

                    if(maxWidth/ratio < maxHeight){
                        margin = maxHeight - maxWidth/ratio;
                        marginHalf = margin/2;
                        $(this).css("margin-top", marginHalf);
                    }
                }
                else{
                    $(this).css("height", maxHeight);   
                    $(this).css("width", maxHeight * ratio);    
                }
            }
            else if(width > maxWidth) {
                $(this).css("width", maxWidth); 
                $(this).css("height",maxWidth/ratio);  

                if(maxWidth/ratio < maxHeight){
                    margin = maxHeight - maxWidth/ratio;
                    marginHalf = margin/2;
                    $(this).css("margin-top", marginHalf);
                }
            }
            else{
                $(this).css("height", maxHeight);   
                $(this).css("width", maxHeight * ratio);    
            }
        }
        else{
            if(ratio > 1){
                $(this).css("width", maxWidth);
                $(this).css("height", maxWidth/ratio);

                if(maxWidth/ratio < maxHeight){
                    margin = maxHeight - maxWidth/ratio;
                    marginHalf = margin/2;
                    $(this).css("margin-top", marginHalf);
                }
            }
            else if(ratio < 1){
                $(this).css("height", maxHeight);
                $(this).css("width", maxHeight * ratio);
            }
            else{
                $(this).css("width", maxWidth);
                $(this).css("height", maxHeight);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with doing your DOM work in a directive. That's what directives are for. Use Angular's built-in directives where you can, and build your own where you need to.

Comment: Any updates over here, still stuck with the problem.

Comment: You'd probably get more attention if the question was clearer. "Any ideas" posts are usually considered off-topic, or tend to be less intriguing to would-be volunteers. Maybe edit your post to make it so.